# What does 事前 refer to in this sentence?

Tags: adverbs

What does 事前{じぜん} refer to in this sentence?

> その前提{ぜんてい}であれば、事前{じぜん}にテキストを確認{かくにん}しながら、お客様{きゃくさま}の環境{かんきょう}でトレーニングの準備{じゅんび}ができると思います{おもいます}。

Does it refer to:

1. "checking the text"? -- as in 事前にテキストを確認する。
2. "preparing the training"? -- as in 事前にトレーニングの準備ができる。

For reference, I translated the sentence as:

"If that's the case, then while you confirm the text in advance, you can begin preparing for the training in the client's environment."

Google translated the sentence as:

If that is the case, you will be able to prepare for training in your environment while checking the text in advance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

テキストを確認する and お客様の環境でトレーニングの準備をする will happen at the same time (that's what ながら means, after all). So 事前に modifies *both*, so to speak. In other words, テキストを確認しながらトレーニングの準備 as a whole is what you can do in advance.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thank you :)